# Trying to read Windows 7 Contacts doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, contacts, addressbook

I based my code on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735866.aspx which is quite bugged, after some adaptation of function CreateNewContact() I tried the following.

I don't have errors anymore but nothing is happening :

```
IClassFactory* pFactory = NULL;
HRESULT rc;
rc = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
if (rc == S_OK)
    rc = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_Contact,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,NULL,IID_IClassFactory, (void **) &pFactory);
if (rc == S_OK)
    rc = CreateNewContact( pFactory);
if (rc == S_OK)
    wprintf( L"Created\n");
```

I get "Created" but I don't see any new contact in C:\Users\myself\Contacts but only my existing contacts.

I don't copy CreateNewContact() here as it can be found on the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I have not used the contacts interface before, but from looking at the code, it should make the file in the current working directory
This will probably be where ever your .vcproj or .dsp project file is. You can find this from the Debugging section of the project properties in visual studio

Comment: Yes !!! You're right !!! Looks stupid but I didn't thought about that ! I can confirm the new file is there...

Comment: Now, may I ask you another beginner question, how can I put the file to the right place ? I mean, you could write it directly to C:\Users\dbucher\Contacts, but how to get this path officially from Windows so that it will work on other versions of Windows, other languages, and so on ?

I suppose that I could use SHGetFolderLocation and add "Contacts" ?

Comment: OK found :
SHGetKnownFolderPath and FOLDERID_Contacts

Comment: You need to call SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Contacts, 0, NULL, &szPath); where szPath is a buffer to receive the path
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx